# TextBox not affected with mask I applied for it

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I applied mask with AJAX toolkit in asp.net for textbox but textbox can't be affected with this mask, here is my code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
TagPrefix="ajax" %>    

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:MaskedEditExtender TargetControlID="TextBox1" Mask="99-9999-9999999-999"
        MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"     
        MaskType="Number" InputDirection="LeftToRight" AcceptNegative="None"
 DisplayMoney="None"  
        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" runat="server" ID="mskD" />

 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: No, The application run successfully and open the web page with this textbox when entered text no any mask happened!

Comment: Please I want to know what is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the ToolkitScriptManager instead of the default ASP.NET ScriptManager

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <ajax:MaskedEditExtender runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
    Mask="99-9999-9999999-999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" 
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    MaskType="Number" 
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
    AcceptNegative="Left" 
    DisplayMoney="Left"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"/>
 </div>
```

You might need to include the AjaxMin.dll in your project in order for the ToolkitScriptManager to work.